# Is this ancient explosive mixture mentioned in the Apocrypha plausible?

Tags: daniel, science, apocrypha

I recently decided to read the Apocrypha. Sounded interesting. Anyway, when I got to The Book of Bel and The Dragon, there was this verse, which struck me as particularly interesting:

1:27 Then Daniel took pitch, and fat, and hair, and did seethe them together, and made lumps thereof: this he put in the dragon's mouth, and so the dragon burst in sunder and Daniel said, Lo, these are the gods ye worship.

Now, what I'm wondering (and the only reason I'm bringing this up here), is what would this do? It seems to be an extremely early reference to use of explosives, which is fascinating in a purely historical sense, but what sort of material would actually be formed by boiling a mixture of pitch, fat, and hair? Would this have some explosive tendency, as can be interpreted from the passage? I'm a chemistry major, but I haven't even gone through Organic yet, so if any of you know anything about the properties this would (or would not) have, I would greatly appreciate the knowledge.

Comment: Beef fat (for example) melts (=boils) above 200 deg C at which temperature the alpha keratin (hair) would likely begin to denature and melt itself.  The resulting "goo" would not be explosive.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So,as a result of that combination of pitch, hair,fat,perhaps it could not explode,  but could it at least kill the serpent and perhaps even cause laceration in the serpent?

Comment: It is likely to be toxic, especially with the pitch.  However, if fed to the beast while still very hot, it would cause much damage.

Comment: Thank you and for more clarificaiton, is there like a link or like a chemical formula that can explain how the hair, pitch, and fat can kill a serpent or at the very least explains how a combination like that can be toxic?

Comment: I wonder if this entire verse isnt metaphorical. When the bible talks about the dragon, it is referring to Satan...not a literal animal. I havent read this book in the apochrypha so i dont know the context...just using Bible themes for my thoughts on this as the Bible is considered the authority on who the dragon is.

Comment: I was taught that the dragon ate them and it gummed him up inside, causing him to explode. Susana and Bel and the Dragon are perhaps the world's first detective stories with Daniel as the original Sherlock Holmes.

Comment: Need an oxidizer. Either saltpeter or gwihabaite (the ammonium analogue of saltpetre. It occurs as incrustations and efflorescences on cave surfaces formed by bacterial action on bat guano.)

Comment: One need not interpret this as speaking about flammable substances, since something can explode without any need for fire. Similar to how whales explode on the beach, because of build of up gas. Maybe that's the idea here, that this mixture causes some reaction in the gut of the dragon (people of all cultures called a real creature "dragon," and only in recent centuries has it went extinct or been forgotten or renamed). It also doesn't say this took place instantly.

Comment: I remember reading about the way of hunting white bears (?) by taking the whale baleen, coiling it and encapsulating in the lumps of fat. The bear would eat it, the fat dissolve in the stomach and the baleen uncoil killing the bear. 
Sounds just like your quote.

Answer (score 3):

*"Would this have some explosive tendency, as can be interpreted from the passage?"*

This interpretation is dubious, because the passage does not describe a explosion of the chemical elements in pitch, hair and fat per se. The more likely intent is a bursting of the animal's stomach due to some kind of dragonish indigestion. Pitch, fat and hair do not explode when cooked together, but they would certainly cause severe indigestion. But it is doubtful this would cause the dragon's stomach to explode. Taking the story as literally factual (which I do not), if this happened to be a fire-breathing variety of dragon, anything is possible. Gasses used to produce the dragon-fire might be blocked from escape by the pitch-hairball and then explode when touched off by the dragon's ignition mechanism. So rather than breathing fire, the dragon would explode.

**So no, this mixture itself would not cause an explosion. What the story describes is a dragon being lured to eat and extremely noxious hairball. The hairball itself would not explode, but trapped gasses in the dragon's stomach might rupture its belly, especially if it was a fire-breather. This is a fanciful tale meant to ridicule Babylonian beliefs. There are (and were) no such things as dragons.**

Comment: It is very bold of you to suggest on this very pious site that dragons are not real. In your enlightened view, are daemons real?

Comment: When I said dragons are not real I referred to dragons of the physical type not the type that is equated with Satan in the book of Revelation. I do believe in evil spirits if that's what you mean by daemons. I do not believe in demigods.

Answer (score -1):

> "the young lion and the **dragon** shalt thou trample under feet". Psalm 91:13. KJB. My emphasis.

> "trample the lion and the **dragon**". Psalm 91:13. New American Bible. My emphasis.

Malachi 1:3 "jackals of the desert".ESV. jackals/*tannah* "dragons of the wilderness" KJB.

Jeremiah 51:34 "he has swallowed me like a monster". monster big enough to eat people/*kattannin*

Where did the Middle Ages get the idea of fire breathing dragons from? In "Dinosaurs: Those Terrible Lizards" Dr Gish [a creationist] mentions that the crests on the heads of some duck-billed dinosaurs were the chemical storage tanks for their flame-throwing mechanisms.

We cannot see that today in action. But we can see the Bombadier beetle. This beetle can spray a concoction of chemicals of boiling irritating chemicals from sacks of stuff which violently react when forced together.  Schildknecht has shown that hydrogen peroxide and in a separate sack of hydroquinone can explode when certain enzymes are present.

Dragons feature in many cultures. Bombadier beetles show us how dragons might have produced chemical defence mechanisms. If the "lumps" you mention blocked the flow of chemicals then an internal explosion sounds imaginable.

[3 Books which give background to Bible and science:

"Biblical Creationism". Dr. Henry Morris.

"On the seventh day". edited by John f. Ashton Phd.

"The new answers book 2" Creation/Evolution and the Bible. Ken Ham.]